# JavaScript Regex pattern - baffled

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using XSLT with regexp:match exslt function. The said function takes JavaScript Regex pattern. Therefore I am trying to match a set of numbers 1 thru 3 OR 5 thru 7 OR 9 thru 23.

Following is the regex pattern I've come up with:

```
(^[1-3]$|^[5-7]$|^[9-23]{1,2}$)
```

This regex does NOT match with any value at all. Following alternate pattern is good only to a little extent:

```
(^[1-3]$|^[5-7]$|^9$|^[10-23]{2}$)
```

While this matches with all other expected number values **except 14 thru 19**. Why is it so and how to make the Regex good. BTW, I am using http://www.regextester.com/ to test the pattern matching.

Thank you.

Comment: At first glance, the or operator seems fishy. It might do `$|^` instead of `tokenGroup|otherTokenGroup`, which would make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with strings not numbers so 14 or 19 or 20 are strings of digits not the numbers.

so `[10-23]{2}` will match 0-2, 1,3 or 0,1,2,3 two times. Notice the missing 4-9.

```
(^[1-3]$|^[5-7]$|^9$|^1[0-9]$|^2[0-3]$)
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me understand why it was not giving the wanted result.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets contain characters, not strings. Try this:

```
^([1-35-79]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])$
```

Edit: Tested it, it works.

```
var str="";
for (var i=0; i<30; i++) {
  if (/^([1-35-79]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])$/.test(i+"")) str+=i+' '
}
console.log(str);
```

prints

```
1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have used the regex pattern in XSLT however your solution was helpful for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In regexes, stuff in brackets only denotes one character.  Try:

```
^[1-3]$|^[5-7]$|^9$|^1[0-9]$|^2[0-3]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an integer, test for >0 and < 24 and !=4 and !=8. Keep it simple.

Comment: Yes this is simple and works too. I've oversimplified the problem statement to apply that into the problem context. A different view point of looking at the issue though. Thank you